# On a TemplateRef, is possible to add 'let-x' attributes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The context of the problem is: I'm trying to perform transclusion and passing context variables to inner components.

For example, one snippet code of my initial DOM:

```
<line-container>
  <template> <!-- I have as constraint add 'let-item' to access to the variable -->
    <componentA item="item"></component>
    <componentB item="item"></component>
  </template>
</line-container>
```

This is a component which retrieves its inner content through 'template' tag (@ContentChild), and then using a ngFor passing the template and routing.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'line-container',
  templateUrl: `
           <div *ngFor="let item of items">
             <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" 
                       [ngOutletContext]="{item: item}"></template>
           </div>`
})
export class LineContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  public items: any[];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // this.renderer.setElementAttr...
  }
}
```

As you notice above, I'm missing to add the 'let-item' into the template tag. Unfortunately, this is a constraint I can't do, hence I'm looking the way to add that attribute dynamically.

I thought using:

```
this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement,
                                  'let-item', 'item');
```

But I noticed always the value of the nativeElement is a comment:  and it's not able to find the ElementHTML to attach that property. Any idea of how to declare this template variable into this template tag?

Comment: Why don't you use simple Input decorator to pass the parameters? Why do you need a template here?

Comment: As I'm using a transclusion concept, I learned that ComponentA and ComponentB need to be grab through the Template tag